# Parse through Cisco Config

Tags: python, cisco, configparser

I been trying to write a Python script to go through 20 some cisco configurations.

So Far, I got a script to work on one config and it parsed out the interfaces that do not have `802.1x authentication*` interface commands.

I'm having trouble removing the `interface Tengig` and `interface vlan*` from the list. What is the best way to do that? I tried the following ways below with no luck. Maybe I'm just using them wrong?

```
list.remove(Interface Vlan*) 

for item in list(NoDot1x):
  somelist.remove("Interface Vlan*")
```

Code:

```
    #Int Modules
    from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

    #Define what to Parse
    parse = CiscoConfParse("/home/jbowers/Configs/SwithConfig")

    #Define all Interfaces without Authentication * commands
    all_intfs = parse.find_objects(r"^interf")
    NoDot1x = list()
    NoDot1x = parse.find_objects_wo_child(r'^interface', r'authentication')

   #Display Results
   for obj in NoDot1x:
       print obj.text

   #Remove Uplinks
   for item in list(NoDot1x):
     somelist.remove("Interface Vlan*")
```

Here the output for #Display Results.

```
interface Port-channel1
interface FastEthernet1
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/1
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/2
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/3
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/4
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/5
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/6
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/7
interface TenGigabitEthernet5/8
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/1
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/2
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/3
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/4
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/5
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/6
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/7
interface TenGigabitEthernet6/8
interface GigabitEthernet7/23
interface GigabitEthernet8/17
interface GigabitEthernet9/2
interface Vlan1
```

Comment: In `somelist.remove("Interface Vlan*")` the `*` doesn't work as a wildcard character. You can use regex to do that or `for i in somelist: if "Interface Vlan" in i: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remove function offered by the list object in Python will attempt to find an exact match to the string entered and remove if found, if not it will error.

```
#Remove Uplinks
for item in list(NoDot1x):
 somelist.remove("Interface Vlan*")
```

The above will not utilize the wildcard character "*". 
I think you want something more like:

```
for item in list(NoDot1x):
 if "Interface Vlan" in item:
  somelist.remove(item)
```

If you need more complexity look at the re import.

Comment: So (item) will be any match of interface vlan. It seems like I was close to it . I’ll try as soon as possible.

Comment: I got it to work with      for item in NoDot1x:
 if "Interface Vlan":
  NoDot1x.remove(item)